# tail -f, multi sed

Tags: sed, tail

I can do

```
tail -vf -c5 thefile    \
    | cat -n            \   
    | sed -E 's/a/b/g'  \
    ;
```

But the following gives no output.

```
tail -vf -c5 thefile    \
    | cat -n            \   
    | sed -E 's/a/b/g'  \
    | sed -E 's/f/F/g'  \
    ;
```

Why?

Comment: -u solved the problem.

Comment: Yes, which is why that's a duplicate

Comment: Ok. Maybe phrasing a question in a few different ways will make it more findable on the internet. Or we can just close it.

Comment: Don't worry, closing as a dupe is precisely the best way to make the question more findable as you say. Now that the question is closed as a dupe, anyone who finds this will be redirected to the dupe. Closing isn't deleting, we actually want duplicates since they can act as signposts directing you to the right place to the the answer. See [When merging questions, leave the duplicate one as a placeholder](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16437)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` is buffering its output. Use the `-u` option (if present, e.g. GNU sed) to flush the buffers more aggressively.

You can also use the `stdbuf` tool which modifies the buffering behaviour:

```
tail -vf -c5  thefile | cat -n | stdbuf -oL sed -E 's/a/b/g' | sed -E 's/f/F/g'
```

Comment: Which `sed` implementations have this? Is it GNU-specific? It [isn't POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) and it's not in [BSD `sed`](https://man.openbsd.org/sed).

Comment: @terdon: Yes, it's present in GNU sed. I added an alternative solution using `stdbuf`.